# Intellij IDEA converts text to tags in a html file

Tags: intellij-idea

As the title states, Intellij Idea converts the text in the html file to tag when I press space. For example, if I type "test" and press space inside the html file, the text is automatically converted to `<test></test>`. How/Where can I change this ?

Comment: It might be Zen coding functionality, check Settings/Editor/Live Templates and disable Zen HTML.

Comment: I just tried it, it doesn't work. Thank you anyway.

Comment: It might be a bug in IntelliJ because I think this should disable it. When I disable it and do `ul>li` and hit tab it still does ZEN coding expansion... Maybe try to report it as a bug on youtrack.jetbrains.com if you're still having issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please go to 'Preferences|Editor|Emmet|Expand abbreviation with' and set the option to Tab (it's a default one) instead of Space.

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixed my problem.